# Accessing Keys Arrays in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Hey everyone am having trouble Accessing object keys to get value ,
my data is structured like this :

```
$userCustomErrors = array(
            'motherboard' => array('socketError' => 1, 'socketError2' => 0 ,'SataNumbers' => 0,'m2Slots' => 0,'RamType' => 0,'RamNumber'=>0,'RamCapacity' => 0,'Mobosize' => 0),
            'cpu'=> array('integratedGraphics'=>0,'RamTypeC' => 0,'RamCapacityC' => 0,),
            'gpu'=> array('GPUError' => 0,'GPULength' => 0,'powerGPU' => 0),
            'cooler'=>array('AirHeight' => 0,'waterRad'=>0),
            'case'=>array('35Numbers' => 0,'25Numbers' => 0,'psuExist'=>0),
            'psu'=>array('statpower'=>0,'TotalPowerConsum'=>0)
        );
```

am trying to acces it this way in my `twig` file :

```
{% for key,Error in userCustomErrors %}
{{ Error["motherboard"]["socketError"] }}
{% endfor %}
```

but am getting this error :

```
Key "motherboard" for array with keys "socketError, socketError2, SataNumbers, m2Slots, RamType, RamNumber, RamCapacity, Mobosize" does not exist.
```

I tried the attribute in the Twig Documentation but nothing seem to work , if anybody willing to help , Thank you

Comment: What is unclear about this error? If you want to display a single value from this array of arrays why don't you simply write `{{userCustomErrors["motherboard"]["socketError"]}}`?

Comment: you're right , thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access a single property, only use:

```
{{ Error["motherboard"]["socketError"] }}
```

If you want to iterate through the array, you need this:

```
{% for key,Error in userCustomErrors %}
    {% for key2,Error2 in Error %}
        <p>{{ key }}, {{ key2 }} => {{ Error2 }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

That way you can iterate through all values

Answer (score 1):

try

```
{% for key,Error in userCustomErrors %}
     {{ Error["socketError"] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer provided by @Crozin in the comment is the right answer :

```
{{userCustomErrors["motherboard"]["socketError"]}}
```